# Unable To open software via active Directory users

Tags: samba

Recently, I have built a samba ad server with an Ubuntu client. When a user is logged into the user desktop as an active directory none of the ubuntu software such as blender, gmip, vlc, and the Ubuntu software store will open. Gimp will load on the menu bar and so will ubuntu software, but nothing opens.